# Sort Divs because of childNode Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

Here is short example of my HTML Code:

```
<div id="feedDiv">
  <div class="articleDiv">
     <div id="pictureDiv">
     </div>
     <div id="ConentDiv">
           <h1> Headline </h1>
           <p> Description </p>
           <p class="toolbar">  
                <a class="thumbsUpNumber">86</a>
                <a class="thumbsDownNumber">79</a>
                <a class="commentNumber"> 32 </a> 
           </p>
     </div>
     <div id="UrlDiv">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to order the #articleDivs in #feedDiv numerically based on the thumbsUpNumbers of each toolbar.

I tried already something like this:

```
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $(".articleDiv").sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).find(".thumbsUpNumber").text() > $(b).find(".thumbsUpNumber").text();
    });

    numericallyOrderedDivs.each(function (i, item) {
        $("#feedDiv").append(item);
    });
```

But nothing works...

Comment: It appears like you have multiple divs `articleDiv` and that is the problem if they all have the same ID, An Id should always be unique

Comment: Replace the id="articleDiv" for class="articleDiv" and you will can have many. Sort them like this:  $(".articleDiv").sort(function (a, b) {...

Comment: Even if i change the id's to class, nothing happens.

Comment: @Lizz Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $(".articlesDiv").sort(function(a, b) {
  var contentA = parseInt($(a).find(".thumbsUpNumber").text());
  var contentB = parseInt($(b).find(".thumbsUpNumber").text());
  return (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : 0;
});

numericallyOrderedDivs.each(function(i, item) {
  $("#feedDiv").append(item);
});
```

But I have to tell you that you need to slow things down, You got so many errors in your code, that its a wonder if it works.

`<div id="pictureDiv>` is missing `"` at the end. same for `<div id="ConentDiv>`, `<div id="UrlDiv>`

**demo**

```js
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $(".articlesDiv").sort(function(a, b) {
  var contentA = parseInt($(a).find(".thumbsUpNumber").text());
  var contentB = parseInt($(b).find(".thumbsUpNumber").text());
  return (contentA > contentB) ? -1 : (contentA < contentB) ? 1 : 0;
});

numericallyOrderedDivs.each(function(i, item) {
  $("#feedDiv").append(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="feedDiv">
  <div class="articlesDiv">
    <div class="pictureDiv">
    </div>
    <div class=" ConentDiv">
      <h1> Headline </h1>
      <p> Description </p>
      <p class="toolbar">
        <a class="thumbsUpNumber">86</a>
        <a class="thumbsDownNumber">79</a>
        <a class="commentNumber"> 32 </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="UrlDiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="articlesDiv">
    <div class="pictureDiv">
    </div>
    <div class=" ConentDiv">
      <h1> Headline </h1>
      <p> Description </p>
      <p class="toolbar">
        <a class="thumbsUpNumber">90</a>
        <a class="thumbsDownNumber">9</a>
        <a class="commentNumber"> 40 </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="UrlDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, Thank you! The code above was only to show what i want to do. The real code is different. i realized my typing erros already...

Comment: @Lizz If the problem is solved, consider marking the answer as accepted so others know it has been solved